# radio button selection in expandable list view

Tags: java, android, xml, expandablelistview

am developing an android app using eclipse. In my app I've made an expandable List view which contains radio buttons as children. When I click on on any row's radio button it gets selected but when I go to click on any other Row's radio button the previous radio buttons gets unselected. Here is the screenshot.

[image]

I want every radio button selected permanently of every row on which I click until I'll go to another activity.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure about android but grouping radio buttons help in this scenario.

Comment: Radio buttons are in group. Every row has child in radio button group.

Comment: Use [RadioGroups](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html)

Comment: I've used radio groups and I've studied this documentation but I couldn't found any help. The problem is that radio group is in layout and this layout is child of every row. So it means every row will have radio group and radio buttons with same id's.